# How to convert a function into a Pipe Function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a function that I am trying to convert into a pipe function but I am still unsure after reading the documentation on angular's website.

After following the documentation on their website it has left me still kind of confused.

```
checkBoolean() {
    if (boolean) {
      return 'true';
    } else if (!boolean) {
      return 'false';
    } else {
      return 'true';
    }
  }
```

The code works fine in this method but I am wanting to switch it to a pipe function.

Comment: Have you [read the docs](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes)? Also A boolean is either true or false, so it doesn't make sense to have three cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'bool'
})
export class BoolPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any): string {
    return value ? 'true' : 'false';
  }
}
```

in your template use it with

```
{{ yourBoolProperty | bool }}
```

You can scaffold up a new pipe with the cli by typing "ng g p Bool" or "ng generate pipe Bool"